# Symfony2 mapping onetomany manytone

Tags: orm, doctrine, symfony, mapping

I am developing an application using symfony2 and using orm.yml files for mapping the entities into the database. The problem comes when trying to create the database tables for two entities that share a onetomany relationship (Anotatzea.php and Dokumentua.php). When running `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` it shows the next error

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  The autoloader expected class "Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity\Anotatzea" to be defined in file "/var/www/Symfony/app/../src/Anotatzailea/AnotatzaileaBundle/Entity/Anotatzea.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

The entities have the following code:

```
<?php

namespace Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity\Dokumentua
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Dokumentua")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Dokumentua
{
    /**
     * @var integer $DokId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DokId", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $DokId;

    /**
     * @var string $Izenburua
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Izenburua", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $Izenburua;

    /**
     * @var string $Egilea
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Egilea", type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $Egilea;

    /**
     * @var date $ErregistroData
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ErregistroData", type="date")
     */
    private $ErregistroData;

    /**
     * @var boolean $DokEgoera
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DokEgoera", type="boolean")
     */
    private $DokEgoera;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Anotatzea", mappedBy="Dokumentua")
     */
    protected $Anotatzeak;

    /**
     * Get DokId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getDokId()
    {
        return $this->DokId;
    }

    /**
     * Set Izenburua
     *
     * @param string $izenburua
     */
    public function setIzenburua($izenburua)
    {
        $this->Izenburua = $izenburua;
    }

    /**
     * Get Izenburua
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getIzenburua()
    {
        return $this->Izenburua;
    }

    /**
     * Set Egilea
     *
     * @param string $egilea
     */
    public function setEgilea($egilea)
    {
        $this->Egilea = $egilea;
    }

    /**
     * Get Egilea
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEgilea()
    {
        return $this->Egilea;
    }

    /**
     * Set ErregistroData
     *
     * @param date $erregistroData
     */
    public function setErregistroData($erregistroData)
    {
        $this->ErregistroData = $erregistroData;
    }

    /**
     * Get ErregistroData
     *
     * @return date 
     */
    public function getErregistroData()
    {
        return $this->ErregistroData;
    }

    /**
     * Set DokEgoera
     *
     * @param boolean $dokEgoera
     */
    public function setDokEgoera($dokEgoera)
    {
        $this->DokEgoera = $dokEgoera;
    }

    /**
     * Get DokEgoera
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getDokEgoera()
    {
        return $this->DokEgoera;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Anotatzeak = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

<?php

namespace Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Anotatzea;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity\Anotatzea
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Anotatzea")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Anotatzea
{
    /**
     * @var integer $AnotId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="AnotId", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $AnotId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dokumentua", inversedBy="Anotatzeak")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="DokId", referencedColumnName="DokId")
     */
    protected $Dokumentua;

    /**
     * Get AnotId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAnotId()
    {
        return $this->AnotId;
    }

    /**
     * Set Dokumentua
     *
     * @param Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity\Dokumentua $dokumentua
     */
    public function setDokumentua(\Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity\Dokumentua $dokumentua)
    {
        $this->Dokumentua = $dokumentua;
    }

    /**
     * Get Dokumentua
     *
     * @return Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity\Dokumentua 
     */
    public function getDokumentua()
    {
        return $this->Dokumentua;
    }
    /**
     * @ORM\prePersist
     */
    public function setUpdatedValue()
    {
        // Add your code here
    }
}
```

And the orm.yml files:

```
Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity\Dokumentua:
  type: entity
  table: Dokumentua
  fields:
    DokId:
      type: integer
      id: true
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      unique: false
      nullable: false
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
    Izenburua:
      type: string
      length: 30
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      unique: false
      nullable: false
    Egilea:
      type: string
      length: 40
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      unique: false
      nullable: false
    ErregistroData:
      type: date
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      unique: false
      nullable: false
    DokEgoera:
      type: boolean
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      unique: false
      nullable: false
  OneToMany:
    Anotatzeak:
      targetEntity: Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity\Anotatzea
      cascade: {  }
      mappedBy: Dokumentua
      inversedBy: null
      orphanRemoval: false
      cascade: ["persist", "merge","remove"]
      orderBy: null
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }

Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity\Anotatzea:
  type: entity
  table: Anotatzea
  fields:
    AnotId:
      type: integer
      id: true
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      unique: false
      nullable: false
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
  manyToOne:
    Dokumentua:
      targetEntity: Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity\Dokumentua
      cascade: {  }
      mappedBy: null
      inversedBy: Anotatzeak
      joinColumns:
        DokId:
          referencedColumnName: DokId
      orphanRemoval: false
  lifecycleCallbacks: { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace name in the second entity file is wrong.

Replace:

```
namespace Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Anotatzea;
```

with:

```
namespace Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity;
```